# Unhide and get input from button during while loop iPhone app

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uikit

I'm building betting functionality with a human and computer players in Swift for iPhone. I start a while loop for the betting process, iterating through each player. If it's a computer player, autobetting functions are called. If it's a human player, I want to unhide action buttons (bet, check, fold, etc) and wait for input from user before moving on in betting while loop. (simplified code below) For some reason unhiding the buttons never executes, even though a print statement just after unhide is successfully printed. Also while loop seems to skip waiting for user input before continuing on. What is the "proper" way to structure this to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for any help/insights.

```
listOfPlayers = [computer1, player1, computer2]

while !bettingRoundComplete {
    for player in listOfPlayers {
        if player == computer1 {
            autoBet()
        }
        if player == player1 {
            betButton.isHidden = false
            checkButton.isHidden = false
            var playerFinishedTurn = false
            while !playerFinishedTurn {
                  // wait for player to enter input via buttons (which should be unhidden but are not)
                  // do some things with input
                  // flip playerFinishedTurn flag to true
        }
        if player == computer2 {
            autoBet()
        }
        // if bettingRoundComplete, exit loop (global variable flag triggered within betting functions that are called during while loop execution)
    }
}
```

Comment: In what context do you call this code, where is the asynchronous part in this? Any reason not to run autoBet for the computer players directly when the user press the betButton?

Comment: Yes, the user bet depends on what the computer players chose to do and the betting order changes every round. The problem is that the program basically just skips waiting for the player input and moves on to the next player in the list. I'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: That’s because you are looping over all players. The computer actions are separate events and needs to be handle on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding of how event-driven apps work. Your app gets notified about an event like a user action, runs through your code to respond to that action, then returns and waits for something else to happen. You can't have a while loop that waits for user action, because while you are your while loop you don't let the user respond. You need to refactor your code to act like a state machine where it goes into a "collect user input" mode.